# Need help to read out the output of a subprocess

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, sudo, eof

My python script (python 3.4.3) calls a bash script via subprocess.

```
OutPST = subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True)
```

It works, but the problem is, that I only get half of the data. The subprocess I call, calls a different subprocess and I have the guess, that if the "sub subprocess" sends the EOF, my programm thinks, that that´s it and ends the check_output.

Has someone an idea how to get all the data?

Comment: [NO "I'm new in python" please.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: What's the value of `cmd`? Please show compilable code.

Comment: half of the data? have you tried to add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to also capture error stream?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) unless you really need that fine grained of control over talking to the processing via its stdin (or doing something else while the process is running instead of blocking for it to finish). It makes capturing output super easy:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

result = run(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```

If you want to merge stdout and stderr (like how you'd see it in your terminal if you didn't do any redirection), you can use the special destination `STDOUT` for `stderr`:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT

result = run(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print(result.stdout)
```